# Intend Chrome via html a tag href

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, hyperlink

When a link is clicked on Instagram, it opens on Instagram built-in browser.
In my page, I have some links that I want they open in Chrome if a user clicks on them.

Is there any way to do it?

For example, we can intend WhatsApp via  tag like this: `whatsapp://send?text=${message}`

I'm looking for a solutation to indent Chrome if is its support.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Chrome doesn't have their own URI but only the one it uses in its own browser for settings, etc: `chrome://settings`. If you need Chrome for something to work properly, I'd personally suggest looking into how the Instagram browser is built and dedicate your code to it - the use of Chrome is no longer needed then and stays in the environment of Instagram.